# Electron Builder issue

Tags: npm, electron, nsis, electron-builder

electron builder - 23.6.1
node-14.15.0

Hi,

I am trying to create exe (using electron.net) i was unable to do so. i Get the below error when trying the build the exe :

/*build error when building the exe using electron*/

```
"Package Electron App for Platform win...
npx electron-builder --config=./bin/electron-builder.json --win --x64 -c.electronVersion=23.2.0
npx: installed 184 in 29.4s
â€¢ electron-builder version=24.9.1 os=10.0.17763
appPackageFile=E:\JenkinsWorkspace\workspace\SSNETExeDEV\SSNETWebSync\SSNETWeb\obj\desktop\win\package.json
â€¢ packaging platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=23.2.0   appOutDir=E:\JenkinsWorkspace\workspace\SSNETExe-DEV\SSNETWebSync\SSNETWeb\bin\Desktop\win-unpacked
â€¢ building target=nsis file=E:\JenkinsWorkspace\workspace\SSNETExe-  DEV\SSNETWebSync\SSNETWeb\bin\Desktop\SSNETDEV Setup 2024.1.16.exe   archs=x64 oneClick=false    perMachine=true
â¨¯ C:\Windows\TEMP\electron-builder-cache\nsis\nsis-3.0.4.1\Bin\makensis.exe process failed   ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE
Exit code:
1
Output:
Command line defined: "APP_ID=com.SSNETDEV.app"
Command line defined: "APP_GUID=ff3d6a64-94c9-5a37-9f5e-ee768b9668ed"
Command line defined: "UNINSTALL_APP_KEY=ff3d6a64-94c9-5a37-9f5e-ee768b9668ed"
Command line defined: "PRODUCT_NAME=SSNETDEV"
Command line defined: "PRODUCT_FILENAME=SSNETDEV"
Command line defined: "APP_FILENAME=SSNETDEV"
Command line defined: "APP_DESCRIPTION="
Command line defined: "VERSION=2024.1.16"
Command line defined: "PROJECT_DIR=E:\JenkinsWorkspace\workspace\SSNETExe-DEV\SSNETWebSync\SSNETWeb\obj\desktop\win"
Command line defined: "BUILD_RESOURCES_DIR=E:\JenkinsWorkspace\workspace\SSNETExe-DEV\SSNETWebSync\SSNETWeb\obj\desktop\win\build"
Command line defined: "APP_PACKAGE_NAME=ssnetdev"
Command line defined: "MUI_ICON=E:\JenkinsWorkspace\workspace\SSNETExe-DEV\SSNETWebSync\SSNETWeb\obj\desktop\win\bin\Files\AppIcon\SSNETIcon.ico"
Command line defined: "MUI_UNICON=E:\JenkinsWorkspace\workspace\SSNETExe-DEV\SSNETWebSync\SSNETWeb\obj\desktop\win\bin\Files\AppIcon\SSNETIcon.ico"
Command line defined: "APP_64=E:\JenkinsWorkspace\workspace\SSNETExe-DEV\SSNETWebSync\SSNETWeb\bin\Desktop\ssnetdev-2024.1.16-x64.nsis.7z"
Command line defined: "APP_64_NAME=ssnetdev-2024.1.16-x64.nsis.7z"
Command line defined: "APP_64   _HASH=F61F6890D770CBCA93824E1B8575D03C029945467D3C421C585ABBD9F712057AC43B66DF1575C80DB327DFD99CE749714DC8B5BF5B94DE8453EF79DC581EFFAD"
Command line defined: "APP_64_UNPACKED_SIZE=1163368"
Command line defined: "APP_INSTALLER_STORE_FILE=ssnetdev-updater\installer.exe"
Command line defined: "COMPRESSION_METHOD=7z"
Command line defined: "MULTIUSER_INSTALLMODE_ALLOW_ELEVATION"
Command line defined: "INSTALL_MODE_PER_ALL_USERS"
Command line defined: "INSTALL_MODE_PER_ALL_USERS_REQUIRED"
Command line defined: "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory"
Command line defined: "SHORTCUT_NAME=SSNETDEV"
Command line defined: "UNINSTALL_DISPLAY_NAME=SSNETDEV 2024.1.16"
Command line defined: "MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP=${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\nsis3-metro.bmp"
Command line defined: "MUI_UNWELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP=${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\nsis3-metro.bmp"
Command line defined: "ESTIMATED_SIZE=1151914"
Command line defined: "COMPRESS=auto"
Command line defined: "BUILD_UNINSTALLER"
Command line defined: "UNINSTALLER_OUT_FILE=E:\JenkinsWorkspace\workspace\SSNETExe-DEV\SSNETWebSync\SSNETWeb\bin\Desktop__uninstaller-nsis-ssnetdev.exe"
Processing config: C:\Windows\TEMP\electron-builder-cache\nsis\nsis-3.0.4.1\nsisconf.nsh
Processing script file: "" (UTF8)

Error output:
!include: could not find: "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\4088\node_modules\electron-builder\node_modules\app-  builder-lib\templates\nsis\include\StdUtils.nsh"
Error in script "" on line 1 -- aborting creation process
failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: C:\Windows\TEMP\electron-builder-cache\nsis\nsis-3.0.4.1\Bin\makensis.exe process failed     ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE
Exit code:
1
Output:
Command line defined: "APP_ID=com.SSNETDEV.app"
Command line defined: "APP_GUID=ff3d6a64-94c9-5a37-9f5e-ee768b9668ed"
Command line defined: "UNINSTALL_APP_KEY=ff3d6a64-94c9-5a37-9f5e-ee768b9668ed"
Command line defined: "PRODUCT_NAME=SSNETDEV"
Command line defined: "PRODUCT_FILENAME=SSNETDEV"
Command line defined: "APP_FILENAME=SSNETDEV"
Command line defined: "APP_DESCRIPTION="
Command line defined: "VERSION=2024.1.16"
Command line defined: "PROJECT_DIR=E:\JenkinsWorkspace\workspace\SSNETExe-DEV\SSNETWebSync\SSNETWeb\obj\desktop\win"
Command line defined: "BUILD_RESOURCES_DIR=E:\JenkinsWorkspace\workspace\SSNETExe-DEV\SSNETWebSync\SSNETWeb\obj\desktop\win\build"
Command line defined: "APP_PACKAGE_NAME=ssnetdev"
Command line defined: "MUI_ICON=E:\JenkinsWorkspace\workspace\SSNETExe-DEV\SSNETWebSync\SSNETWeb\obj\desktop\win\bin\Files\AppIcon\SSNETIcon.ico"
Command line defined: "MUI_UNICON=E:\JenkinsWorkspace\workspace\SSNETExe-DEV\SSNETWebSync\SSNETWeb\obj\desktop\win\bin\Files\AppIcon\SSNETIcon.ico"
Command line defined: "APP_64=E:\JenkinsWorkspace\workspace\SSNETExe-DEV\SSNETWebSync\SSNETWeb\bin\Desktop\ssnetdev-2024.1.16-x64.nsis.7z"
Command line defined: "APP_64_NAME=ssnetdev-2024.1.16-x64.nsis.7z"
Command line defined: "APP_64   _HASH=F61F6890D770CBCA93824E1B8575D03C029945467D3C421C585ABBD9F712057AC43B66DF1575C80DB327DFD99CE749714DC8B5BF5B94DE8453EF79DC581EFFAD"
Command line defined: "APP_64_UNPACKED_SIZE=1163368"
Command line defined: "APP_INSTALLER_STORE_FILE=ssnetdev-updater\installer.exe"
Command line defined: "COMPRESSION_METHOD=7z"
Command line defined: "MULTIUSER_INSTALLMODE_ALLOW_ELEVATION"
Command line defined: "INSTALL_MODE_PER_ALL_USERS"
Command line defined: "INSTALL_MODE_PER_ALL_USERS_REQUIRED"
Command line defined: "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory"
Command line defined: "SHORTCUT_NAME=SSNETDEV"
Command line defined: "UNINSTALL_DISPLAY_NAME=SSNETDEV 2024.1.16"
Command line defined: "MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP=${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\nsis3-metro.bmp"
Command line defined: "MUI_UNWELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP=${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\nsis3-metro.bmp"
Command line defined: "ESTIMATED_SIZE=1151914"
Command line defined: "COMPRESS=auto"
Command line defined: "BUILD_UNINSTALLER"
Command line defined: "UNINSTALLER_OUT_FILE=E:\JenkinsWorkspace\workspace\SSNETExe-DEV\SSNETWebSync\SSNETWeb\bin\Desktop__uninstaller-nsis-ssnetdev.exe"
Processing config: C:\Windows\TEMP\electron-builder-cache\nsis\nsis-3.0.4.1\nsisconf.nsh
Processing script file: "" (UTF8)
Error output:
!include: could not find: "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\4088\node_modules\electron-builder\node_modules\app-  builder-lib\templates\nsis\include\StdUtils.nsh"
Error in script "" on line 1 -- aborting creation process
at ChildProcess. (C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\4088\node_modules\electron-builder\node_modules    \builder-util\src\util.ts:251:14)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:520:26)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\4088\node_modules\electron-builder  \node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)"
```

Can someone direct me to the right way please.

Tried Clearing the cache data  but did not help

Comment: And if you install/run electron as a normal user and not SYSTEM?